# checkar checkbox do gridview baseado no valor do banco de dados

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net

Minha aplicação precisa liberar tipos de acessos, por exemplo, temos 5 filiais e tal pessoa precisa acessar conteúdos de apenas 3 filiais.

O usuário ADM, pode criar ou editar novos usuários. Na hora de editar preciso carregar os acessos que ele já tem e também o que ele pode vir a ter.

Criei uma gridview e coloco todas as filias lá, e no banco de dados temos as informações das que ele já tem acesso, por usuário.

Criação da gv:

```
  DataTable tblACESSOfilial = new DataTable();
  tblACESSOfilial.Columns.Add("ACESSOFILIAL", Type.GetType("System.String"));
  tblACESSOfilial.Columns.Add("LOCALDEACESSO", Type.GetType("System.String"));

  String[] tipofilial = new String[18];
  tipofilial[0]  = "1-1-1";
  tipofilial[1]  = "1-4-1";
  tipofilial[2]  = "1-5-7";
  tipofilial[3]  = "1-7-6";
  tipofilial[4]  = "1-123-8";
  tipofilial[5]  = "1-124-8";
  tipofilial[6]  = "1-1-2";
  tipofilial[7]  = "1-1-3";
  tipofilial[8]  = "1-1-4";
  tipofilial[9]  = "1-1-6";
  tipofilial[10] = "1-9-126";
  tipofilial[11] = "5-4-1";
  tipofilial[12] = "5-1-4";
  tipofilial[13] = "5-1-6";
  tipofilial[14] = "5-1-7";
  tipofilial[15] = "5-1-8";
  tipofilial[16] = "5-1-9";
  tipofilial[17] = "10-1-2";

  String[] descfilial = new String[18];
  descfilial[0]  = "1-1-1 (Nome)";
  descfilial[1]  = "1-4-1 (Nome)";
  descfilial[2]  = "1-5-7 (Nome)";
  descfilial[3]  = "1-7-6 (Nome)";
  descfilial[4]  = "1-123-8 (Nome)";
  descfilial[5]  = "1-124-8 (Nome)";
  descfilial[6]  = "1-1-2 (Nome)";
  descfilial[7]  = "1-1-3 (Nome)";
  descfilial[8]  = "1-1-4 (Nome)";
  descfilial[9]  = "1-1-6 (Nome)";
  descfilial[10] = "1-9-126 (Nome)";
  descfilial[11] = "5-4-1 (Nome)";
  descfilial[12] = "5-1-4 (Nome)";
  descfilial[13] = "5-1-6 (Nome)";
  descfilial[14] = "5-1-7 (Nome)";
  descfilial[15] = "5-1-8 (Nome)";
  descfilial[16] = "5-1-9 (Nome)";
  descfilial[17] = "10-1-2 (Nome)";

  for (int x = 0; x <= 17; x++)
  {
    DataRow rows = tblACESSOfilial.NewRow();
    rows["ACESSOFILIAL"] = tipofilial[x];
    rows["LOCALDEACESSO"] = descfilial[x];
    tblACESSOfilial.Rows.Add(rows);
  }

  this.dgvACESSOfilial.DataSource = tblACESSOfilial;
  this.dgvACESSOfilial.DataBind();
```

Na consulta que tenho é a seguinte:

```
SELECT CODCOLIGADA, CODTIPOCURSO, CODFILIAL FROM POLIS_NCADMINFILIAL (NOLOCK)" +
        "WHERE CODUSUARIO = '@CODUSUARIO'
```

Essa consulta pode retornar de 0 a 17 linhas.

Caso o conteúdo esteja no consulta ele faz um check na gridview na seguinte forma:

```
List<domUsuario> list2 = dao.ListaTodosFilial(this.txtCODUSUARIO.Text);
        foreach (GridViewRow row in this.dgvACESSOfilial.Rows)
        {
          if (list2[row.RowIndex].COLIGADAIN.Count() > 0)
          {
            string local = list2[row.RowIndex].COLIGADAIN + "-" + list2[row.RowIndex].CODTIPOCURSO + "-" + list2[row.RowIndex].CODFILIAL; ==>ERRO AQUI
            if (local.Contains(row.Cells[1].Text))
            {
              CheckBox chkRow = (row.Cells[0].FindControl("chkRowfilial") as CheckBox);
              chkRow.Checked = true;
            }
          }
        }
```

O problema é que está me retornado o erro onde identifiquei como "==>ERRO AQUI":

O índice estava fora do intervalo. Ele deve ser não-negativo e menor que o tamanho da coleção.\r\nNome do parâmetro: index

Alguém poderia me ajudar no que eu poderia estar fazendo? Desde já agradeço.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Na minha consulta retorna varias linhas, então criei um index nela para ter o controle:

```
int index = 0;

        while (reader.Read())
        {
          domUsuario item = new domUsuario();
          item.COLIGADAIN = reader["CODCOLIGADA"].ToString();
          item.CODTIPOCURSO = reader["CODTIPOCURSO"].ToString();
          item.CODFILIAL = reader["CODFILIAL"].ToString();
          item.INDEX = index;

          Lista.Add(item);

          index++;
        }
```

Na hora de verificar, para cada linha da consulta ele verifica na gridview inteira:

```
List<domUsuario> list2 = dao.ListaTodosFilial(this.txtCODUSUARIO.Text);

        list2.ForEach(delegate (domUsuario dom)
        {
          string local = list2[dom.INDEX].COLIGADAIN.ToString() + "-" + list2[dom.INDEX].CODFILIAL + "-" + list2[dom.INDEX].CODTIPOCURSO;

          foreach (GridViewRow row in this.dgvACESSOfilial.Rows)
          {
            if (local.Contains(row.Cells[1].Text))
            {
              CheckBox chkRow = (row.Cells[0].FindControl("chkRowfilial") as CheckBox);
              chkRow.Checked = true;
              break;
            }
          }
        });
```

Answer (score 2):

Resposta editada:

```
List<domUsuario> list2 = dao.ListaTodosFilial(this.txtCODUSUARIO.Text);

foreach (GridViewRow row in this.dgvACESSOfilial.Rows)
{
    if(row.RowIndex < 0)
        continue;

    var values = list2
         .Where(o => o.COLIGADAIN.Any())
         .Select(o => $"{o.COLIGADAIN}-{o.CODTIPOCURSO}-{o.CODFILIAL}")
         .ToArray();

   if (values.Any(o => o.Contains(row.Cells[1].Text))
   {
       CheckBox chkRow = (row.Cells[0].FindControl("chkRowfilial") as CheckBox);
       chkRow.Checked = true;
   }
}
```

Comment: então, dependendo da consulta ele roda e faz o check em alguns items e depois da este erro.. acabou não funcionando o jeito que falou

Comment: o erro está dando por que a quantidade de linhas do datagridview e items na lista são diferentes

Comment: sim, mas não sei que maneira para "ignorar" quando é diferente.. pq preciso passar mesmo sendo diferentes, para que possa dar o check

Comment: Editei a resposta, vê se é isso que espera..

Comment: na verdade ainda não, conversando com um cara aqui do trabalho.. percebi que precisava fazer dois foreach, uma para a consulta do select e outra para a gridview e comparar e deu certo.. logo posto a resposta

Comment: o lambda do values faz um foreach nos valores do select, mas blz, espero que dê certo.

Comment: ainda sou novo e não manjo muito, agradeço a sua ajuda.. durante esse tempo tava tentando resolver e deu certo de outra maneira

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/103859/discussion-between-pedrobelino-and-weiner-lemes).